# How to do live concurrent editing?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, juggernaut

I am trying to build a rails app that's basically just a text-editor (with some additional features I can't find anywhere else - which is why I'm building it)

One of the core features is live concurrent editing, or real-time collaborative editing (whatever you want to call it).

So far I have set up the site with a plugin called [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/). This gives me the ability to send, either from a client or the server, any Javascript I want to every other client. So when someone types something I can send what that person has typed to every other client, without the other clients having to poll the server.

The problem I have boils down to me not knowing what algorithm to use for solving conflicts and doing this the best way possible. I have read up a bit on [Operational Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation), but just simple don't know how to sensibly implement it with the Javascript/Rails-solution I have now.

I want something like OT, but don't know how to implement it and don't know where to start.
Any help on how to implement this would me very happy!

Comment: Interesting problem from a usability perspective...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [MobWrite](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobwrite/)

Comment: I had not seen this, as I understand it Bespin is using MobWrite, so I'm definitely gonna take a look at this!

Answer (score 4):

I think that Google has (or will soon release), the OT logic of Wave as open source.

Maybe check the [Wave Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/) Open Source project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Bespin](http://labs.mozilla.com/bespin/) by Mozilla? For inspiration I mean -- I understand that you're using Rails.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a complete answer you could have a very interesting insight on how Google Wave does it here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ykZYKCK7AM

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this and I stumbled upon [sharejs](http://sharejs.org/). Hope this helps.